# IE sending through multiple unrequested requests for parent URL

Tags: internet-explorer, http

We have a rather large/complex web site (so it's not easy to extract portions of it).  The problem we're having is that IE6/7/8 (but 6 is the worst) are sending through multiple requests for the parent of a URL (which fails, a different point).  As an example, if you visited (dummy domain name obviously):

http://www.example.com/view/event/123/456/78

We'd get 8-20 requests for:

http://www.example.com/view/event/123/456/

appear in the Apache log. We've tried:

- Disabling all plugins (including toolbars, Flash, etc)
- Disabling scripting (e.g. Javascript)

And it still sends through at least one erroneous request. We've viewed the requests through ieHttpHeaders so the browser is aware of them (i.e. it's not prefetching by the network's proxy).

Any ideas? What can else could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with the .htaccess, have you defined some routing rules?

Comment: Nope, there's no .htaccess file.